# Share memory performance in Linux over windows (Synchronization overhead : Semaphore)

Tags: c, linux, performance, semaphore, shared-memory

This post is regarding calculating the performance of share memory in Linux over windows.
I am newbie to Linux development.
I have write client server application that calculates how many packets(size 2048 bytes) from  share memory are transferred from client (process 1) to server (process 2) in 1 seconds.

In windows I am using
CreateFileMapping
OpenFileMapping
MapViewOfFile
functions & for share memory synchronization I am using named events(createevent) in both client & server
so that at a time read or write operation can be performed in share memory block.
also I am using circular buffer inside structure as share memory block so it will became 512 share block of size 4096

```
    struct block{
     BYTE Data[4096];
      long amount;
    }
    struct MemBuffer{
      block m_Blocks[512];
       ...
       ...
    }
```

some sort of logic is implemented so that it will work as FIFO manner.

Now In case of linux
I am using posix share memory api
shm_open
ftruncate
mmap

share memory block is same (as mentioned above for windows)
for synchronization semaphore is used

now performance

windows  count is 700000 packet per seconds
linux    count is 500000 packet per seconds using named semaphore
linux    count is 600000 packet per seconds using unnamed semaphore

according my observation overhead in this whole application is synchronization 
so can anybody suggest me better approach for synchronization or how to improve overall performance of share memory in Linux?

thanks in advance

**update:**

I am using dual boot machine with windows 2003 server & Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.0. machine configuration are as follows Intel Quad Core with 2.4 Ghz , 4GB RAM

Comment: forget to mentioned one thing that i am using dual boot machine with windows 2003 server & Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.0. machine configuration are as follows Intel Quad Core with 2.4 Ghz , 4GB RAM

Comment: you should really post the code, so others can test it too, or look for errors (e.g. wrong initialization of the semaphores, etc). Also, try using mutexes + a cond variable

Comment: mutexes are expensive as they result in eventual syscall and thus a scheduling out of the thread. I would recommend using a spinlock as you are on a multi-cpu machine. One single cpu , mutex should be fine.

Comment: R Jay D : thanks for the addition. i am using event based synchronization example : server is wait mode(sem_wait) when no data to read, when client write data in share memory it raises event(sem_post) so server gets that event at start reading now when reader is reading that same share memory block write cant write in that block in my case i am using circular buffer so u it get 512 block of data for read write so wait events should not occure all the time but i guess it is occuring thats why performance is not that good.

Comment: R Jay D : Now as u told spinlock if i used it then reader & writer will continuosly try read write which i think overhead also event based synchronization cant be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those methods should result in identical memory mappings at the hardware level (unless you are really unlucky and got cache conflict).  So yes, the difference you're seeing is in the implementation of the semaphores.  But don't take my word for it, do the experiment where you're producing and consuming the buffers, only you never actually read or write them.  See if you get the same behavior.

There are lots of libraries out there that have high-performance semaphores.  Try one of them, like [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html).

Comment: R Keith Randall@ thanks for valuable comment. what is exact difference between posix & boost lib semaphore so that it can give high performance

Comment: R Keith Randall@ i hv tested with boost semaphore but performance is same (posix & boost lib)